# JavaFX - Passing values

Tags: java, javafx

Im aware this problem is pretty common, but I'm running out of options. Tried every solution and nothing is working for me.

What I'm trying to do is simply pass some values from 1 JFX window to another.

here is my `login` method inside `loginController` class

```
public void login(ActionEvent event){
    try{
        if(loginModel.isLogin(txtUsername.getText(), txtPassword.getText())){
            try {
                ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
                Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                mainViewController sendHello = loader.<mainViewController>getController();
                sendHello.getUser(txtUsername.getText());
                Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("mainView.fxml").openStream());
                primaryStage.setTitle("Kcalculator");
                primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                primaryStage.setResizable(false);
                primaryStage.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else{
            Alert alert1 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert1.setTitle("Login failed");
            alert1.setHeaderText(null);
            alert1.setContentText("The username or password you have entered is invalid.");
            alert1.showAndWait();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is my `mainViewController` class

```
public class mainViewController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private Label userLbl = new Label();

    public void getUser(String user){
        userLbl.setText("Welcome " + user);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
}
```

after trying several solutions, Im still getting NullPointerException after "successfull" login.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the fxml before `loader.getController` can return anything other than `null`:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

// load fxml
Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("mainView.fxml").openStream());

// get controller created using fx:controller attribute in the fxml
mainViewController sendHello = loader.<mainViewController>getController();

// use controller
sendHello.getUser(txtUsername.getText());
```

Note that the `fx:controller` attribute needs to be assigned the correct value for this to work of course.

Answer (score 0):

I am recently had to develop a login for an app. This app opens the proper view for the users account type. It uses sqlite to store and retrieve info about the users and to store and retrieve encrypted passwords. You might find this helpful.

> Controller

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TextField tfUsername;
    @FXML private PasswordField pfPassword;
    @FXML private Button btnSignIn;

    @FXML
    void handlebtnSignIn(ActionEvent event){

        int userID = 0;
        String username = "", accountType = "";
        byte[] encryptedPassword = null, salt = null;
        if(tfUsername.getText().length() > 0 && pfPassword.getText().length() > 0)
        {
           try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db"); 
                PreparedStatement  stmt = createPreparedStatement(conn, tfUsername.getText());
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery())
            {            
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    userID = rs.getInt("user_id");
                    username = rs.getString("username");
                    encryptedPassword = rs.getBytes("password");
                    salt = rs.getBytes("salt");
                    accountType = rs.getString("account_type");              
                }

                if(tfUsername.getText().equals(username) && authenticate(pfPassword.getText(), encryptedPassword, salt))
                {
                    Stage stage = new Stage();

                    stage.setWidth(1080);
                    stage.setHeight(720);
                    Parent fxmlLoader = null;

                    switch(accountType)
                    {
                        case "administrator":  
                            stage.setTitle("Tech Services Console");
                            System.out.println("I just signed in as an administrator");
                            fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AdminView.fxml"));
                            break;
                        case "collection":
                            stage.setTitle("Collection Console");
                            System.out.println("I just signed in as a collection member");
                            fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CollectionDevView.fxml"));
                            break;
                        case "selector":
                            stage.setTitle("Selector Console");
                            System.out.println("I just signed in as a selector member");
                            fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Selector.fxml"));
                            break;
                    }


                    stage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlLoader));

                    stage.show();
                    ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
                    tfUsername.setText("");
                    pfPassword.setText("");
                }  
                else
                {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    alert.setHeaderText(null);
                    alert.setContentText("Incorrect username or password!");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("Incorrect username or password!");
                alert.showAndWait();
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 
        }        
    }

    @FXML
    void handleEnterButtonPress(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER))
        {
            btnSignIn.fire();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }   

    private PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con, String username) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, username);
        return ps;
    }

    boolean authenticate(String attemptedPassword, byte[] encryptedPassword, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
    {
        byte[] encryptedAttmeptedPassword = getEncryptedPassword(attemptedPassword, salt);
        return Arrays.equals(encryptedPassword, encryptedAttmeptedPassword);
    }

    public byte[] getEncryptedPassword(String password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
    {
        String algorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
        int derivedKeyLength = 160;
        int iterations = 2000;
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, derivedKeyLength);
        SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);

        return f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    }

    public byte[] generateSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
    {    
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        random.nextBytes(salt);

        return salt;
    }
}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane id="apMain" onKeyReleased="#handleEnterButtonPress" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="425.0" stylesheets="@../css/log_in_stylesheet.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="planningchart3.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10.0" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="69.0" prefHeight="284.0" prefWidth="448.0" vgap="10.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="25.0" left="25.0" right="25.0" top="25.0" />
         </padding>
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="tfUsername" promptText="username" text="sedj601" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="pfPassword" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="107.0" promptText="password" text="hello" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <Button fx:id="btnSignIn" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebtnSignIn" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Sign in" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Text id="welcomeText" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Welcome" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Tahoma" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Label styleClass="outline" text="User name: " textFill="#03244d" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cambria Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font></Label>
            <Label styleClass="outline" text="Password: " textFill="#03244d" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cambria Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font></Label>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I set the username to sedj601 and password to hello. You might want to get rid of that part.

> This is was helpful [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/secure-password-storage-donts-dos-and.html).
>
> This is the part that will probably be more helpful with your question.

```
try
{
    if(tfUsername.getText().equals(username) && authenticate(pfPassword.getText(), encryptedPassword, salt))
    {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setWidth(1080);
        stage.setHeight(720);
        Parent fxmlLoader = null;

        switch(accountType)
        {
            case "administrator":  
                stage.setTitle("Tech Services Console");
                System.out.println("I just signed in as an administrator");
                fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AdminView.fxml"));
                break;
            case "collection":
                stage.setTitle("Collection Console");
                System.out.println("I just signed in as a collection member");
                fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CollectionDevView.fxml"));
                break;
            case "selector":
                stage.setTitle("Selector Console");
                System.out.println("I just signed in as a selector member");
                fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Selector.fxml"));
                break;
        }

        stage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlLoader));
        stage.show();
        ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
        tfUsername.setText("");
        pfPassword.setText("");
    }  
    else
    {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Incorrect username or password!");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
} 
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("Incorrect username or password!");
    alert.showAndWait();
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
} 
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | IOException ex)          
{
    Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```